# CSS - wrap nav around logo image (Responsive)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, nav

I would like to wrap a nav around a centered logo image, see a example [her](http://www.symbolphoto.com/).

In addition I would like this nav to scale in a responsive way, when I re-size the browser window.

This is my non-responsive attempt so far! [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3kwo4L6/)

```
<div id="nav">
    <img src="http://pre08.deviantart.net/ae58/th/pre/f/2012/120/5/9/thundercats_1985_2011_logo_by_pencilshade-d4y2uzr.png" alt="Mountain View" class="logo"/>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Menu 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!--end nav-->
```

Comment: Why not put the logo image as the middle `li`?

Comment: maybe so https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ma5n11v0/?

Comment: If you look at the example...they are actually using **two menus**...one left and one right.

Comment: Here's one I like from a colleague - http://codepen.io/wolfcry911/pen/HyLdg

Comment: Thank you all! @Dmitriy, your suggestion rocks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in a kind of table structure?

Or there is a prity lib for your problem:

http://zikes.github.io/circle-menu/

http://zikes.github.io/circle-menu/examples/

Comment: Thank you for answering! I am not sure if this is it.. I would like the menu items to be displayed horizontally with the logo image in the middle, and not circled around the logo image!